# background color issue in datagrid (WPF)

Tags: c#, datagrid, background-color

How to select a row(e.g.first row in datagrid) and set its background color to be e.g. red in C#?

I have following code in my program:

```
gameDataGrid.RowBackground = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Red);
```

The output's background is not red.

Comment: Which grid? WinForms? WPF? ASP.Net? Silverlight?

Answer (score 0):

If you are wanting to change multiple rows based on some property, wire up the LoadingRow event and change the DataGridRow's style in the event handler.

Answer (score 0):

in xaml

```
    <DataGrid
                AlternatingRowBackground="AliceBlue"
                CanUserAddRows="false"
                CanUserSortColumns="False"
                Grid.Row="2"
                Foreground="#FF040404"
                Background="#cce6ff"
                VirtualizingStackPanel.VirtualizationMode = "recycling"
                VirtualizingStackPanel.IsVirtualizing = "true"
                EnableColumnVirtualization = "true"
                EnableRowVirtualization = "true"
                x:Name="dvSalesEntryDataGrid"
                AlternationCount="2"
                AutoGenerateColumns="False">
</DataGrid>
```